# can't build projects after update

Tags: ios, xcode

After automatically updating to **10.2.1**  Xcode now can't build anything. and logging this error

> Failed to find or create execution context for description ' System content for IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater  scaleFactor=2x'. These intermediate objects were non-nil: (
>       "IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x

Showcasing that it's in **.storyboard** files

I deleted derived data, and tried to use legacy build system, with no luck

Comment: What have you tried to fix this? Have you deleted derived data and done clean and build etc...

Comment: i did clean build. but isn't clean build would delete the derived ? , however ill delete them and build using legacy system

Comment: Same issue @Fogmeister

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

works for me!

Comment: I also had same issue, after auto update xcode, this solution worked for me as well